# Unable to see access logs in my Google Storage Bucket

Tags: rest, logging, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a sample program using Google Storage service. I am able to set Bucket logging correctly, after setting logging and performing operations for days, still I am not able to see any [csv file as logs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs) in my destination logged bucket.

```
<Logging>
    <LogBucket>
        my_logs
    </LogBucket>
    <LogObjectPrefix>
        log_object_prefix
    </LogObjectPrefix>
</Logging>
```

I am using same above API to set logging. On getting the status of logging on bucket, it show as set logging.

Please let me know what is missing on setting logs?

Thanks in advance for help,

Neelam Sharma

Comment: @Dainius What NSA stands for Google Cloud Storage, can you please explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cloud-storage-analytics@google.com needs to have write permission for your LogBucket as described here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs

Comment: Thanks Travis, please let me know that what will be the scope type for cloud-storage-analytics@google.com, I tried its been added as "GroupByEmail" and "UserByEmail". How much time it take to create logs?