# What is scope type for "cloud-storage-analytics@google.com"?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to set Access Logs to my Bucket using Google Cloud Service. For [creating logs in target bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403805/unable-to-see-access-logs-in-my-google-storage-bucket), I need to update ACL of target bucket as WRITE permission to Google Cloud account - **"cloud-storage-analytics@google.com"**

I have added this email address on target bucket, it has been added via "**GroupByEmail**" and "**UserByEmail**" scope type successfully. Please clarify which scope type is correct to add this email address on target bucket.

How much time it take to create logs?

Thanks,

Neelam Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a group. Use **GroupByEmail**. Here's an example of a valid setting for it.

```
<Entry>
    <Scope type="GroupByEmail">
        <EmailAddress>
            cloud-storage-analytics@google.com
        </EmailAddress>
    </Scope>
    <Permission>
        WRITE
    </Permission>
 </Entry>
```

Access logs are generated on an hourly basis, and storage logs are generated on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I am also able see logs delivered in the bucket only which was set as target bucket having ACL permission as WRITE permissions to "cloud-storage-analytics@google.com" as GroupByEmail scope and bucket having permission set as UserByEmail does not contain any logs, so GroupByEmail is correct, documentation should clarify that settings.